# How get value from JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I convert collection to JSON string.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall = api.Wall.Get(-group.Id.Value, out totalCount, count);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wall, Formatting.Indented);
```

get string json like this

```
 [
  {
    "Id": 144159,
    "Text": "Если",
    "Likes": {
      "Count": 9307,
      "UserLikes": false,
      "CanLike": true,
      "CanPublish": true
    },
    "PostType": "post",
    "PostSource": {
      "Type": "api",
      "Data": null
    },
    "Attachments": [
      {
        "Instance": {
          "AlbumId": -7,
          "Photo75": "http://cs629506.vk.me/v629506780/3a56/Sn3eI5qEtc0.jpg",
          "Photo130": "http://cs629506.vk.me/v629506780/3a57/tKRNTJlSH1s.jpg",
          "Photo604": "http://cs629506.vk.me/v629506780/3a58/wyz6H7Py_8U.jpg",
        },
        "Type": "VkNet.Model.Attachments.Photo, VkNet, Version=1.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
      }
    ]
```

How I may get value from "Photo604"? I want get picture url. Please Help me!

Comment: Why are you serializing the collection at all? Why not just get `wall[0].Attachments[0].Instance.Photo604`?

Comment: Can you show the `Post` type?

Comment: Yes, it's Post  type

Comment: that is not a valid json string; you may have broke it making it anonymous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast Instance to a Photo first like this:

```
var photo = wall[0].Attachments[0].Instance as Photo
if (photo != null)
    var uri = photo.Photo604
```

Of course there is no error checking here. You should check for nulls and array lengths before accessing or you may get a null reference exception.